# Is running Javascript on server side protect my javascript source code from being stolen?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a calculator. Here client can not load the js file, only calculator UI will load here. I want to take input from client, then sever will process it using javascript(is this possible?) and give only a text  output (calculator result).
By doing this can I protect my js source code of calculator?
Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe with something like node. Otherwise any JavaScript you present to the user can be "stolen". Why not use something like PHP if you just "want to take input from client, then sever will process it"?

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen please don't be rude

Comment: You can [run JavaScript on the server](https://nodejs.org/en/) and make your calculation logic inaccessible to the user this way. May not be worth the effort though.

Comment: Actually I am new at programing ,coding and web development. I have not a clear idea about PHP, node js. And Idea of making a calculator orprogram was just an example.. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much Timo and j08691 I will try to understand PHP and NodeJS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can have a [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) server that takes an input from a GET or a POST call and returns the result of the computation.
It doesn't matter really if it's JavaScript, PHP or whatever other language running on the server. From the client perspective there is no way to actually see the source code running in the server (unless you have a security breach, but that's another story).